# How to reference specific column and row IDs in a COUNTIF formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data sheet that looks like this.

```
     Proj1 Proj1 Proj1 Proj2 Proj2
Req1.  x    x            o     x       
Req2   x          x            x
```

I am using the below formula to check range B2:E2 on my data sheet and return results in the second sheet.

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Data'!B2:E2;"x")>0;"x";IF(COUNTBLANK('Data'!B2:E2)=COLUMNS('Data'!B2:E2);"0";"o"))
```

However instead of giving this range (B2:E2) in the formula, I would like to reference column & row ids (e.g. Proj1 & Req1) and run the formula for the data that matches this criteria.

Comment: So you want to replicate the behaviour of your formula which would be (1) if at least one "x", result is "x" (2) If as many blank cells as there are columns, result is "0" (3) otherwise "o" , but for matching rows and columns only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this if I've understood requirements correctly:

```
=LET(Proj,$B$1:$F$1,
Req,$A$2:$A$3,
Data,$B$2:$F$3,
Blanks,SUM((Proj=I$1)*(Req=$H2)*(Data="")),
x,SUM((Proj=I$1)*(Req=$H2)*(Data="x")),
IF(x>0,"x",IF(Blanks=COLUMNS(Data),0,"o")))
```

Just pulled down and across:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$E$5="x")*--($A$2:$A$5=I3))>0,"x",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$E$5="")*--($A$2:$A$5=I3))=4,0,"o"))
```

I've added manually the 4 because there are 4 columns but you could replace the 4 with `COUNTA($B$1:$E$1)`

Comment: Thanks, I think this partially helps as now I can reference and get results for the right req from my data, but how do I still ensure that I am getting results for the right project too e.g. proj1?

Comment: @ElvinIbishli this part of the formula `--($A$2:$A$5=I3)` makes sure is the right project. Check how SUMPRODUCT with double unary operators works at https://sprestridge.net/excel/2016/04/06/SUMPRODUCT.html

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns In this case you can dispense with all of the `--` operations.   Excel recasts logical values to binary values as the result of *any* unary mathematical operation being performed on them.  In the double-unary case, that math operation is the `-`.  In your example, all of the logical arrays are already being exposed to a unary math operator, `*`, and thus the recasting will happen.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns but --($A$2:$A$5=I3) this doesn't make sure it's the right project; it only makes sure its the right requirement / row.